# General strategy for copying files in a windows service application

Tags: c#, .net

I need an advice on how to write a windows service application that would monitor changes to a certain folder on a drive and copy changed and newly created files to a certain location. Now, I am going to use FileSystemWatcher for this purpose, but I wonder what would be the best way to deal with the situation when multiple files need to be copied simultaneously? For example, one huge file is still being copied and the event is fired again? Do I need to form some sort of a queue and whenever one file is finished being copied, start the next one? Or maybe create a new thread for each file and take care of the copying in that thread? Also, should I use the File.Copy method, or is there a better/faster way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with the queue. The queue is filled with the file name by the event handler and a background thread processes the queue.
If you are using .NET 4, you can use the [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) and be thread safe.

Non-compiling sample code:

```
class AsyncFileCopier
{
    BackgroundWorker _worker;

    void OnNewFile(string fileName)
    {
        _queue.Enqueue(fileName);
        EnsureWorkerIsRunning();
    }

    void EnsureWorkerIsRunning()
    {
        if(!_worker.IsBusy)
            _worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void OnWorkerDoWork(...)
    {
        string fileName;
        while(_queue.TryDequeue(out fileName)
        {
            CopyFile(fileName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution I know too.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I thought I understood it at first, but now I am a bit confused - what happens if the worker is busy? Does "EnsureWorkerIsRunning()" need to be inside a while (_queue.Count != 0) loop?  Edit: uhm, no that would defeat the purpose. So what happens if the worker is busy, how do I feed it the next file in the queue?

Comment: @AbramovAlexei: If the worker is busy, it is running already, so you don't need to - and can't - start it again.

Comment: So I have a FileSystemWatcher reacting on two files being changed, let's say within 1 second. It takes a backgroundworker 5 seconds to copy the first file, so when my file_changed event fires the second time and sees that the worker is busy, it just ignores it or what?

Comment: No. The background worker is a background thread. It is processing the items in the queue one by one, so in your example, the first file is detected and put into the queue. because the background worker is not yet running `EnsureWorkerIsRunning` starts it. The background worker will dequeue that item from the queue and starts copying it. While it is doing that, the second file is detected and put into the queue. When the background worker is done copying the first file, it dequeues the second file from the queue and copies that too...

Comment: OK, I get it now. My confusion was stemming from the fact that I didn't know what TryDequeue was doing exactly. Basically OnWorkerDoWork won't stop until the queue is empty. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of managing a queue and workers yourself, why not just dispatch to the Thread Pool?

```
// event handler of FS Watcher
await Task.Run(() => File.Copy(...));
```